# Will this circuit work on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: operational-amplifier, raspberry-pi, python, ldr

There a lot of articles on websites regarding the use of LDRs connected to a Raspberry Pi. As an example, using an ADC or using a built in library.

I'm interested with my own design below and since I do not have a Raspberry Pi, I do not know if this work.

Theoretically,  will this work and has anyone tried this before?

[image]

In this circuit, I using an open loop gain comparator with 3 different voltage references: 1V,2V and 3V. When the LDR is at low brightness, U2A will turn on as shown below, at moderate brightness, U1B turn on and- at full brightness all opamps turn on giving out 2V output voltage

Example:

At low brightness, U2A will turn on give 2V.

[image]

These three opamps are connected to 3 GPIOs of a Raspberry Pi which are set as input.

The pseudo-code below will display the seven segment by output result 1,2 and 3:

```
if(pin7==high&&pin8=low&&pin9==low)

{display 1}

if(pin7==high&&pin8==high&&pin9==low)

{display 2}

if(pin7==high&&pin8==high&&pin9==high)

{display 3}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your U1:A is exceeding its maximum input voltage: The LM358 wants at least 1 V ([datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/lm358-d.pdf) ON Semi, Fig. 4, p. 6) headroom between positive input and supply voltage, and you only have 0.5 V.

Comment: could use an LM339 with a 5V supply powering it  instead, and pull-ups to 3.3v on the outputs.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the flaw in the design, didn't realize that, in that case, I can correct it to 3.5V so opamp output will be 2.5v which is still below 3.3v which is max allowable voltage for Pi.