# Do I need to be concerned about the output current of the Raspberry Pi GPIO or voltage?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, raspberry-pi

Previously I asked this question [Will this circuit work on a Raspberry Pi?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/572635/will-this-circuit-work-on-a-raspberry-pi/572640#572640) about the design of an LDR circuit by using an op-amp connected to a Raspberry Pi.

Now I have a question.

If my open loop gain is less than 3.3V (maximum voltage which may possibly fry the GPIO,) do I still have to consider how much current flows into the GPIO?

My understanding of op-amps is that it is an auto load matching device (as long as it is not overload.) I understood it is the current that can fry the GPIO of a Raspberry Pi but isn't if the voltage level is kept within the safe level, then current should be within the safe level as well using the concept V=IR?

Comment: Ohm's law doesn't apply to semiconductor devices, but yes, as long as the voltage is within spec the current will be also. (assuming the GPIO is functioning as an input!)

Comment: Actually for CMOS gates, Ohms Law works well for for measuring if it is a constant RdsOn,for outputs, but the input impedance is too high here to be of any concern

Comment: Thanks for the verification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but you can, but be reasonable and not have to go through the calculations for each pin. Just the heavily loaded ones (relative term). Check as many as you need to to be sure the total load is less then what the micro can supply. Check the micro data sheet and it will tell you the maximum power the chip can supply in total and what each port can supply. For example the micro has 10 GPIOs that are driving 20Ma each, and the ports are rated at 25mA each, so far OK, that is 200mA. Now let's assume the spec states it can supply 100mA in total, sounds like a lot. Hmmmm! This will eventually fry the micro as it is rated at 100mA max output and you connected 200mA. It comes down to understanding your loads and what they do to the micro. We can make some adjustments if all the loads are not on at the same time, and that includes reset and power on. The numbers chosen are to keep the math simple, not relative to any specific micro.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you:
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104825/what-are-the-max-current-rating-for-3-3v-and-5v-rail-of-the-rpi-4b#104832

It seems you can draw max 800ma at 3.3v

Comment: 800 mA is the current you can draw from the 3.3V rail.  You **cannot** draw 800 mA from a single GPIO.

Comment: Check my answer.